# Difference between type casting (char*) and (size_t)

Tags: c, casting

I was trying to find the difference of two pointers by subtraction, but one is `int *` and other is `char *`. As a result it gave me an error, as I expected, because of incompatible pointer type.

```
int main() {  
   char * ca="test";
    int *ia=malloc(12);
    *ia=45;
    printf("add char * =%p, add int = %p \n", ca, ia);
    printf("add ca-va * =%p\n", ca-ia);
        return(0);
}
```

> test3.c:22:35: error: invalid operands to binary - (have ‘char *’
>   and ‘int *’)

However, when I type cast `int*` to `size_t` I was successfully able to subtract the address. Can some explain what exactly `size_t` did here?

```
int main() {  
   char * ca="test";
    int *ia=malloc(12);
    *ia=45;
    printf("add char * =%p, add int = %p \n", ca, ia);
    printf("add ca-va * =%p\n", (ca-(size_t)ia));

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: This is just pointer arithmetic. Operators exist for (pointer type) +/- (integer type) and for (pointer type) - (same pointer type) but not for (pointer type) - (different pointer type).

Comment: It is undefined behavior. Correct is `intptr_t pc = (void*)ca, pa = (void*)ia; printf("add ca-va = %" PRIdPTR "\n", pc - pa);`

Comment: Never ever use casts unless you really know what you are doing, are aware of and accept all implications! On a sidenote: even if both pointers had the same type the difference would not be allowed. See http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p9 and related.

Comment: @PaulHankin: That avoids undefined behavior, but it doesn't necessarily give you a meaningful result. I've worked on systems (Cray vector systems) where the result could be meaningless; pointer-to-integer conversion just copied the representation, and `char*` pointers were word pointers with a byte offset in the high-order 3 bits, managed by software.

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 problems here:

The difference between two pointer values is counted in units of the data type the pointers point to. This cannot work if you have two different data types.

Pointer arithmetics is only allowed within the same data object. You may only subtract pointers that point to the same array or to one block of dynamically allocated memory.
This is not the case in your code.

Subtracting pointers that do not match those criterias doesn't make much sense anyway.

The compiler is right to complain.

Comment: "Pointer arithmetics is only allowed within the same data object" ??? what about `argv[5]` ? This is pointer arithmetics... Your answer is not clear.

Comment: I am pretty sure that `argv[]` is one single array.

Comment: well, for exemple, `int main(int argc, char **argv) { }` (or `char *argv[]` that doesn't matter), `argv` is NOT an array and `argv[5] == *(argv + 5)` which is pointer arithmetic.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html, for more exemple of what is an array and what is a pointer.

Comment: The last time I checked the standard it was an array: "5.1.2.2.1 Program startup .... — If the value of argc is greater than zero, **the array members argv[0] through argv[argc-1]** inclusive shall contain pointers to strings, which are given implementation-deﬁned values by the host environment prior to program startup... "

Comment: Standard sometime contains wrong terminologie, the simple way to check if `argv` is an array is to use `sizeof`, try `sizeof argv`, try `sizeof *argv`, this always give you `char **` and `char *`. But WHATVER, give random pointer `ptr`, `ptr[5] == *(ptr + 5)` and this is pointer arithmetic, so "Pointer arithmetics is only allowed within the same data object.", is totally wrong.

Comment: @Stargateur while you're right that `argv` is actually a pointer (to the first element of an array), I think what Gerhardh is saying is that you're only allowed to use pointer arithmetic to get to other parts of memory of the same object. e.g. `int a[2]; a[1]` is valid but `int a[2]; a[100]` is not.

Comment: @Stargateur See section 6.5.6.9 of the C standard. "When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object,
or one past the last element of the array object."

Comment: @Stargateur while you may be technically correct that *within* main the parameter is decayed to a pointer, the data structure that is passed to main is an array. The limits of pointer arithmetics are defined by this array, not by the decayed pointer.

Comment: @PaulHankin That is perfectly true and that doesn't say "Pointer arithmetics is only allowed within the same data object."... did you read my message, maybe I'm not clear ?

Comment: @Stargateur: `argv` points to the first of a *contiguous sequence of values*, which is basically what an array *is*.  Pointer arithmetic is meaningful among elements of `argv`.

Comment: Voted down because this does not answer the question. The question asks what the conversion to `size_t` is doing, but this answer discusses only pointer arithmetic, which the question states is expected not to work between different types.

Comment: @Stargateur See https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p8:  "If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; **otherwise, the behavior is undefined**."

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes and ? I never say the contrary... Please read what I say, I already code a memory allocator, 3 servers in C, I'm not a noob... I know all this. I'm just saying that ptr + 5, is pointer arithmetic between a pointer and an integer which is NOT "the same data object". Words are important, and this answer is wrong to say that. You are all thinking that pointer arithmetic is only between pointer !

Comment: @Stargateur You can have a pointer to the middle of an array and the pointer arithmetic rules mentioned still apply. e.g. `int a[5]; int* p = a+2; /*valid:*/p[-1]; /*invalid:*/p[5];` All that matters is what contiguous "data object" (array, etc) the pointer points to, even if it's in the middle of it.

Comment: @Kevin Yes... I know... you don't understand a thing of what I'm saying. `p` in your context is NOT AN ARRAY.

Comment: @Stargateur https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p7: "For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to an object that is not an element of an array behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type."  You know, something like `argv` in `int main( int argc, char **argv )...` after it decayed to a pointer when passed from the code that created the argument vector and then called `main()`.

Comment: @Stargateur: The statement that "Pointer arithmetics is only allowed within the same data object" is perhaps not expressed very clearly, but it does make sense. For example, `argv` points to the initial element of an anonymous array of `char*` created before `main` is called. Valid pointer arithmetic (pointer +/- integer) on `argv` is bounded by the size of that array. If you add or subtract an integer value from `argv`, either the result points to an element of that anonymous array, or it points just past the end of it, or the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @Stargateur When did I say that `p` is an array and why does that matter? It points inside an array. All pointer arithmetic on `p` must stay inside (or 1 after the last element) of the array `a` to remain valid.

Answer (score 1):

This is just pointer arithmetic.

For some pointer `ptr` and integer `offset`, `ptr - offset` means *the address `offset` elements before `ptr`*. Note that this is *elements* (whatever the pointer points to), not bytes. You can also use addition here. `ptr[i]` is shorthand for `*(ptr + i)`.

For two pointers of the same type (e.g. both `char*`), `ptr1 - ptr2` means *the number of elements between the 2 pointers*. e.g. if `ptr1 - ptr2 == 5`, then `ptr1 + 5 == ptr2`.

For two pointers of different types (e.g. `char*` and `int*`) `ptr1 - ptr2` doesn't make any sense.

In your first piece of code the error occurs because you're trying to subtract pointers of different types. The second piece of code works because your cast is causing it to use the `ptr - offset` version. But this is is certainly not what you actually want because a pointer was converted to an offset and the result is a pointer.

What you probably want is something that Paul Hankin mentioned in a comment:

```
intptr_t pc = (intptr_t)ca;
intptr_t pa = (intptr_t)ia;
printf("add ca-va = %" PRIdPTR "\n", pc - pa);
```

This converts the pointers into integer types capable of holding an address and then does the subtraction. You will need to `#include <inttypes.h>` to get `PRIdPTR` (`inttypes.h` internally includes `stdint.h` which provides `intptr_t`).

Comment: and could be undefined behavior if `(intptr_t) ca` doesn't fit into `(intptr_t)`, you should use `uintptr_t` and do the difference like this `pc > pa ? pc - pa : pa - pc`.

Comment: @Stargateur Do you mean `pc-pa` doesn't fit into an `intptr_t`? If so, I agree.

Comment: @PaulHankin overflow of signed integer is UB, I don't even know why `intptr_t `exist, difference between pointer should always do this. Plus `(intptr_t) ca` is enough to have potential UB if `ca` is too big for `intptr_t`. Of couse, in most case that should work, but LLVM optimization could surprise more than one developer with signed integer overflow. `ptrdiff_t` has this problem too... even with `uintptr_t` standard don't guarantee that will work... operation between pointer is often undefined behavior --'. But `uintptr_t` will work on all systems that I know.

Answer (score 1):

`size_t` is an integer type. When a pointer is converted to an integer type, the result is implementation-defined (if it it can fit in the destination type; otherwise the behavior is not defined by the C standard).

Per a non-normative note in the C standard, “The mapping functions for converting a pointer to an integer or an integer to a pointer are intended to be consistent with the addressing structure of the execution environment.” On machines with simple memory address schemes, the result of converting a pointer to an integer is typically the memory address. The remainder of this answer will assume we have such a C implementation.

Thus, if `ca` points to an array of `char` at address 9678, and `ia` points to some allocated memory at 4444, the result of converting `ia` to `size_t` would be 4444. Then, when 4444 is subtracted from `ca`, we are not subtracting two pointers but rather are subtracting an integer from a pointer. In general, the behavior of this is not defined by the C standard, because you are only allowed to add and subtract integers to pointers within the bounds of one array, and 4444 is far outside of `ca` in this example. However, what the compiler **may** do is simply convert the integer to the size of the pointed-to elements and then subtract the result from the address. Since `ca` points to `char`, and the size of `char` is one byte, converting 4444 to the size of 4444 `char` elements is simply 4444 bytes. Then 9678−4444 is 5234, so the result is a pointer that points to address 5234.

When you need to convert a pointer to an integer, there is a better type for this, `uintptr_t`, defined in the `<stdint.h>` header. (Comments have pointed out `intptr_t`, but you should use the unsigned version unless there is specific reason to use the signed version.) Then, if you convert both pointers to `uintptr_t`, as with `(uintptr_t) ca - (uintptr_t) ia` you will avoid the problem of the first pointer possibly pointing to some type whose size is not one byte. Then result on machines with flat memory address spaces will typically be the difference between the two addresses.

Since implementation-defined and undefined behavior are involved here, this is not something you can rely on, and you should not manipulate pointers this way in normal code.

Comment: I think there's a good reason to use the signed version `intptr_t` here -- the result of subtracting the two values is logically a signed value, and `(uintptr_t)ca - (uintptr_t)ia` will be huge and not useful if the first value is smaller than the second. Subtracting two `intptr_t` may result in UB if there's overflow or underflow, but that's only a theoretical concern and won't occur on the sort of computers for which subtracting pointers makes sense (ie: all common modern computers).

Comment: A language-lawyer concern: `(intptr_t)(void*)ca - (intptr_t)(void*)ia` is more accurate -- the int pointer types are only guaranteed to be able to represent `void*` pointers, so an intermediate conversion to `void*` is necessary. Of course, in practice there is no problem with omitting this conversion.